# Firefox Mac - Force local HTML files to open in a new tab instead of a new window

Tags: macos, firefox

If I'm developing a site locally and try to open an HTML file that's located on my hard drive by either double clicking it or dragging it onto the Firefox dock icon, it opens in a new window. This obviously gets annoying if you are working on several files at once. Any way to force all files to open in a new tab rather than a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option can be set in the Firefox preferences here http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/tab-preferences-and-settings

You should also check the value of `browser.link.open_newwindow` and make sure it is set to the default value of 2 - http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction

Comment: It ended up actually being http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_external that I needed to set, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.